# Simple recursion step by step: Why does "return 1" return something other than 1?

Tags: javascript

In the simple recursive function below, where is the "cumulative" value being stored as it continues to go through the recursive function over and over.  I am confused as to how `return 1` returns the factorial value rather than just `1`.

```
function factorial(x) 
{ 
  if (x === 0){
    return 1;
  }
   return x * factorial(x-1);
         
}
```

Comment: It only returns 1 when x is 0.

Comment: Passing 0 and 1 both return 1. 0 returns 1 because of your if statement. Passing 1 returns 1 because X * the factorial of 1 minus 1 is 1. (1 X factorial(1-1))

Comment: Right, but if I do `factorial(4)`, I go through the recursive function a few times and eventually `x === 0` and the base case is hit.  Why does it return `24` and not `1`?  Where is that cumulative value being stored?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down frame by frame, when you do `factorial(5)` you get-

```
factorial(5) =
  5 * factorial(5 - 1) =
    4 * factorial(4 - 1) =
      3 * factorial(3 - 1) =
        2 * factorial(2 - 1) =
          1 * factorial(1 - 1) =
            1
```

Notice that the last step is just 1 because `factorial(1 - 1)` is 1 (`return 1;` when `x` is 0)

Accumulate all that step by step from the bottom up and you get-

```
factorial(5) =
  5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
      ^
      4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
          ^
          3 * 2 * 1 * 1
              ^
              2 * 1 * 1
                  ^
                  1 * 1
                      ^ 1
```

To illustrate this in the code-

- `factorial(5)` returns `5 * factorial(4)`
- To actually return `5 * factorial(4)`, we need to evaluate `factorial(4)` - `factorial(4)` returns `4 * factorial(3)`

  so `5 * factorial(4)` turns into `5 * 4 * factorial(3)`
- Now we have to evaluate `factorial(3)` to be able to return `5 * 4 * factorial(3)` - `factorial(3)` is `3 * factorial(2)`

  So `5 * 4 * factorial(3)` becomes `5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(2)`
- Now for `factorial(2)` - that is `2 * factorial(1)`

  So `5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(2)` becomes `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(1)`
- `factorial(1)` becomes `1 * factorial(0)`

  So `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(1)` becomes `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * factorial(0)`
- Finally `factorial(0)` returns 1

  So `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * factorial(0)` becomes `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1`

So the actual return of `factorial(5)` - `5 * factorial(4)` expanded to `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1` - which is what the function returns

Comment: thanks Chase.  Right, I get that part but where is the accumulated value being stored?  How is that carried over?

Comment: `x * factorial(x-1)` it's being accumulated by this line

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't understand the factorials, I invite you to read the wikipedia article on this subject https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial.

A factorial is calculated this:
ex: 10! = 10 × 9 × 8 × 7 × 6 × 5 × 4 × 3 × 2 × 1 × 0!

In other words
10! = 10 × 9! ,hence the return x*factorial(x-1)

when you get to the end, you have to have a value (otherwise you have an infinite loop).

And you have to have a factorial of 0 => 0! = 1.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question.

> where is the "cumulative" value being stored as it continues to go through the recursive function over and over?

It is not being stored anywhere, at least not in a way you might be thinking.
Each time you call recursive function you a passing a new function argument, which act as "accumulated value", but in really it is a new function call with new arguments passed to it. Until the condition is fulfilled your function will keep calling itself.